# connection string in web config being ignored

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, connection-string

Here is a problem I've never seen before and can't seem to even find a work-around that doesn't involve brute hard-coding, much less a solution. When trying to connect to a SQL Server Express 2012 database in a WCF Service App, my calls to the `ConfigurationManager` do not show the connection string added to the Web.config. Here's the connection string...

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SRC.RMX.DB" connectionString="Data Source=COMPUTER-NAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=src.db;Integrated Security=True" providerName="MSSQL"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

It's the exact same connection string format I've added in countless real and test apps and a service very similar to the one being built has the exact same connection (they're supposed to work side by side in the same system) with a different name, and works with no issues. And amazingly, if a test console app is added to the project with this connection string in its app.config, it runs with no problem.

But try and run unit tests for a web service and it can't find it in the web.config. When debugging, it's not even listed among the connection string options. I would understand if there was an issue with the configuration file, but I'm pretty much just using the one created by VS2012 with the project and have only added the connection string as shown below...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SRC.RMX.DB" connectionString="Data Source=COMPUTER-NAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=src.db;Integrated Security=True" providerName="MSSQL"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas what could be the culprit? Is there anything I can do here to make this connection string finally show up? What could I be missing?

SOLVED:

Whoops. Embarrassed to admit it, but I pulled down a version of the .config file that did not have the connection string for my unit tests and was 100% sure I did. Just when you think you're sure, it pays to check again...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested what effect it might have, but your provider should be `System.Data.SqlClient` for MSSQL Server. I haven't seen `MSSQL` provider name before.

Comment: It has no effect whatsoever. I use the `MSSQL` for a database access wrapper and as noted in the original question, the same exact connection string with a different name works for a different project laid out the same exact way and a console app using the exact same connection string in its app.config file. You don't even have to provide a provider name for a valid connection.

Answer (score 0):

try recreating the configuration file and copy/paste your custom properties into it. could just be a character or delimiter out of place somewhere. if it works, you could winmerge and see what it was.

Answer (score 0):

If it is done for unit tests,  you should add connString to unit tests project config as well.

You can also try to debug it.